# Extend sums and products functions

Tags: lisp, scheme, sicp

> Exercise 2.57.  Extend the
>   differentiation program to handle sums
>   and products of arbitrary numbers of
>   (two or more) terms. Then the last
>   example above could be expressed as
>
> `(deriv '(* x y (+ x 3)) 'x)`
>
> Try to do this by changing only the
>   representation for sums and products,
>   without changing the deriv procedure
>   at all. For example, the addend of a
>   sum would be the first term, and the
>   augend would be the sum of the rest of
>   the terms.

I wrote the following solution.

```
(define (deriv exp var)
  (cond ((number? exp) 0)
        ((variable? exp)
         (if (same-variable? exp var) 1 0))
        ((sum? exp)
         (make-sum (deriv (addend exp) var)
                   (deriv (augend exp) var)))
        ((product? exp)
         (make-sum
          (make-product (multiplier exp)
                        (deriv (multiplicand exp) var))
          (make-product (deriv (multiplier exp) var)
                        (multiplicand exp))))
        ((exponentiation? exp)
         (make-product (exponent exp)
                       (make-exponentiation (base exp) (- (exponent exp) 1))))
        (else
         (error "unknown expression type -- DERIV" exp))))

(define (variable? x) (symbol? x))

(define (same-variable? v1 v2)
  (and (variable? v1) (variable? v2) (eq? v1 v2)))

(define (make-sum . a)
  (define (iter sum rest) 
    (cond ((null? rest) (if (zero? sum) '() (list sum)))
          ((=number? (car rest) 0) (iter sum (cdr rest)))
          ((number? (car rest)) (iter (+ sum (car rest)) (cdr rest)))
          (else (cons (car rest) (iter sum (cdr rest))))))
  (let ((result (iter 0 a)))
    (if (= (length result) 1)
        (car result)
        (cons '+ result))))

(define (=number? exp num)
  (and (number? exp) (= exp num)))

(define (make-product . a)
  (define (iter product rest)
    (cond ((null? rest) (if (= 1 product) '() (list product)))
          ((=number? (car rest) 1) (iter product 
                                         (cdr rest)))
          ((number? (car rest)) (iter (* product (car rest)) 
                                      (cdr rest)))
          (else 
           (let ((result (iter product (cdr rest))))
             (if (and (pair? result) (eq? (car result) 0))
                 (list 0)
                 (cons (car rest) result))))))
  (let ((result (iter 1 a)))
    (if (= (length result) 1)
        (car result)
        (cons '* result))))

(define (sum? x)
  (and (pair? x) (eq? (car x) '+)))

(define (addend s) (cadr s))

(define (augend s) (if (> (length s) 3)
                       (cons '+ (cddr s))
                       (caddr s)))

(define (product? x)
  (and (pair? x) (eq? (car x) '*)))

(define (multiplier p) (cadr p))

(define (multiplicand p) (if (> (length p) 3) 
                             (cons '* (cddr p))
                             (caddr p)))

(define (exponentiation? x)
  (and (pair? x) (eq? (car x) '**)))
(define (base s) (cadr s))
(define (exponent s) (caddr s))
(define (make-exponentiation m1 m2)
  (cond ((=number? m2 0) 1)
        ((= m2 1) m1)
        (else (list '** m1 m2))))
```

Can it be improved?  In particular, look closely at make-product and make-sum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your have the right ideas for implementing `make-sum` and `make-product`.  You may improve upon them in the following ways, in my opinion.

Within the two functions, you employ an inner function `iter` to partition numeric and non-numeric terms.  Traditionally, one uses the name `iter` to represent an iterative function; your definition, however, is most certainly recursive.  To make it truly iterative, one may use two accumulators--one for the sum of all numeric terms and the other for the rest of the terms.  Then one may return the `cons` of the two accumulators when the iteration terminates.

One may allow `make-sum` (and similarly `make-product`) to handle other sum-type objects in its terms list as well--simply test with `sum?`, then append its terms.

Finally, there are several cases that must be handled when iteration terminates: `rest` may be empty or it may contain one or more items; `sum-numbers` may be zero or non-zero.

Here's an implementation (naming scheme is slightly different from yours--in the `iter` function, `terms` is the list of remaining terms to be iterated upon, `sum-numbers` is the sum of all numeric terms seen so far, `rest` is a list of all non-numeric terms seen so far):

```
(define (make-sum . terms)
  (define (iter terms sum-numbers rest)
    (cond
      ((null? terms) (cons sum-numbers rest))
      ((=number? (car terms) 0) (iter (cdr terms) sum-numbers rest))
      ((number? (car terms)) (iter (cdr terms) (+ sum-numbers (car terms)) rest))
      ((sum? (car terms)) (iter (append (cdar terms) (cdr terms)) sum-numbers rest))
      (else (iter (cdr terms) sum-numbers (cons (car terms) rest)))))
  (let*
      ((result (iter terms 0 null))
       (sum-numbers (car result))
       (rest (cdr result)))
    (if (null? rest)
        sum-numbers
        (if (zero? sum-numbers)
            (if (null? (cdr rest))
                (car rest)
                (cons '+ rest))
            (cons '+ (cons sum-numbers rest))))))

(define (make-product . terms)
  (define (iter terms sum-numbers rest)
    (cond
      ((null? terms) (cons sum-numbers rest))
      ((=number? (car terms) 0) (cons 0 null))
      ((=number? (car terms) 1) (iter (cdr terms) sum-numbers rest))
      ((number? (car terms)) (iter (cdr terms) (* sum-numbers (car terms)) rest))
      ((product? (car terms)) (iter (append (cdar terms) (cdr terms)) sum-numbers rest))
      (else (iter (cdr terms) sum-numbers (cons (car terms) rest)))))
  (let*
      ((result (iter terms 1 null))
       (sum-numbers (car result))
       (rest (cdr result)))
    (if (null? rest)
        sum-numbers
        (if (zero? sum-numbers)
            (if (null? (cdr rest))
                (car rest)
                (cons '* rest))
            (cons '* (cons sum-numbers rest))))))
```

One may also simplify the definitions of `augend` and `multiplicand` by using `make-sum` and `make-product` respectively:

```
(define (augend s) (apply make-sum (cddr s)))

(define (multiplicand p) (apply make-product (cddr p)))
```

Note the similarities between `make-sum` and `make-product`.  It may be possible to factor out some code.  One may also use library functions such as `partition` (if available) to simplify the code.

Comment: I see what you mean about (augend ) and (multiplicand ) as well as the iter/rec naming.  Could you elaborate a bit on why it is better to add the additional (product? ) or (sum? ) test?  I think I understand, but I'm curious what you think.

Comment: @jaresty:  By handling a sum-type object in `make-sum`, the following simplification becomes possible: `(make-sum 2 '(+ 5 x))` => `'(+ 7 x)`